# What might be causing problems publishing binary content to a specific publication in Tridion 5.3?

Tags: publishing, 5.3, binary

We have a LIVE environment in which we publish against 2 servers. Server A publishes content into the broker DB and server B publishes content into the filesystem. The deployer and the web application are located in the same server.

Suddenly we are seeing an error when publishing a page to the file system on the second server. The publication state says `Failed` and the page is published to the server althought the image included in the page is not created.

The weird thing is the same page is published without problems in other languages and there's no localized content.

When I check into the folder `pagemeta` I can find the xml info for the page, but not for the `binarymeta` or `componentmeta` folders. The `componentmeta` must have the image component which contains the image but I can't find it.

Looking into the error description, we don't get too much info:

> An unexpected error occurred processing data null

We have already ensured there is only one deployer running on the server and that the deployer process has the appropriate rights to access the Tridion data folders. Everything seems to be correct there.

Any clue or new vias for exploring?

I checked the cd_broker.log in debug mode but I couldn't get any successful information.

I checked:
- Only one deployer running
I discovered:
- Only happening for certain languages and templates
- Exploring the cd_deployer.log, I got this error (not crystal clear thought)

```
[Error 30-01-2014 16:32:24] An unexpected error occurred processing data null
java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:332)
        at com.tridion.broker.linking.FSCSVLinkInfoHome.getComponentLinkInfoFromFile(FSCSVLinkInfoHome.java:138)
        at com.tridion.broker.linking.FSLinkInfoHome.findByComponent(FSLinkInfoHome.java:158)
        at com.tridion.broker.linking.FSLinkInfoHome.getOldComponentLinksWithoutPage(FSLinkInfoHome.java:245)
        at com.tridion.broker.linking.FSLinkInfoHome.createComponentLinks(FSLinkInfoHome.java:180)
        at com.tridion.broker.linking.FSLinkInfoHome.storeByPage(FSLinkInfoHome.java:84)
        at com.tridion.broker.deploy.PageHandler.deploy(PageHandler.java:124)
        at com.tridion.broker.deploy.DeploymentHandler.deploy(DeploymentHandler.java:152)
        at com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy.processPage(PageDeploy.java:146)
        at com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy.processItem(PageDeploy.java:119)
        at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:81)
        at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:86)
        at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:86)
        at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:86)
        at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.process(SectionVisitor.java:58)
        at com.tridion.deployer.Processor.process(Processor.java:102)
        at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionHandler.process(TransactionHandler.java:307)
        at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionHandler.commitTransaction(TransactionHandler.java:225)
        at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionHandler.handleTransaction(TransactionHandler.java:194)
        at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionHandler.run(TransactionHandler.java:108)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
        at com.tridion.util.LoggingThread.run(LoggingThread.java:120)
```

Comment: This is a pretty old error message, I remember having it back in 5.3 days but not after (and a quick search of my mailbox confirms that), and it looks related to storage layer.

I would recommend looking at your cd_deployer.log, you should have additional information (like a Java stack trace) that might shed some light about why this is happening.

Comment: That error log suggests some issue with the CSV Link Info... you may have to dig into the metadata in those CSV files for the actual items you're publishing, maybe some data is missing or incorrect :(

Comment: Uhmm any help about interpreting the CSV link info? First one is the pageId, but the others? pageId,10020,0,77, /en/blaba.jsp

Comment: probably something like pageId, componentId, positionOnPage, componentTemplatId, pageUrl

Answer (score 2):

sometimes I have seen the error "An unexpected error occurred processing data null" and is
related to the size of the package that is sent to the deployer.

Seems the content for the binaries is not transferred into the deployer because the size exceeds whatever the deployer is allowed to accept

I suggest to run a test, reduce the number of binaries published with the page and see if is properly published.

If that is the case you can increase the volume that the deployer can accept 
in the cd_deployer_conf.xml check the following setting:

If you are using IIS for host the deployer check the following link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded

That error could be associated to the settings if the IIS not able to receive large packages

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps another process on the server kicks-in... like a virus scanner.

Answer (score 0):

Finally as Nunho pointed out it was a problem related with some corrupt csv link info files. Unable to locate them, we just renamed the pagemeta and linkinfo folders and republished again the failing files. It worked! In fact, this approach worked for us due to our web app is accessing to the broker database of node A for link info. And we only needed to publish the phisical file in the machine. Be careful if you access to the link info in the FS.